# Atlas report, different map referenece

Tags: qgis, atlas, reports

QGIS 3.22.4

Scenario:
Shapefile line representing roads (one line per road) `ID=RoadId`
Shapefile point representing trees along the road, `ID=treeId`.
There is a field in the attribute that contents the `RoadId` the tree is attached to.

I have a report based on the tree shapefile that shows 2 times the same map, but with different margin around the tree, with the idea to show the whole road on one, and the stuffs close to the tree on the second.
For showing the whole road, there is a problem = roads can be 200m or 1 km, so I would have a scale that can vary to show the whole road.
With the margin technique, it is obvious that it could not work as expected, so should I try other stuffs, like playing with scale or with limits of scale, but do not know how to use that.
Any idea on how to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Create a buffer around your trees. Choose data driven override for the buffer size. Size should be the distance from the tree to the closest road. Use this expression for that:

```
    length (
        make_line (
            $geometry,
            closest_point (
                overlay_nearest(
                    'road',  -- replace with the name of your road layer
                    $geometry
                )[0],
                $geometry
            )
        )
    )
```

2. Toggle visibility of the buffer layer (make it invisible) and use it as atlas coverage layer.

Like this, every atlas pages shows the tree in the middle and the closest road at the margin of the page, so scale will differ from page to page. Use `Margin around feature` to see more of the road.

---

**Variant**

To get not the nearest street, but nearest road associated with the trees (in my case, field `road_associated` on the `tree` layer, refering to the `road_id` on the layer named `road`), you can use a modified expression:

```
    length (
        make_line (
            $geometry,
            closest_point (
               eval (
                'overlay_nearest(
                    ''road'',   -- modifiy the name of the road layer
                    $geometry,
                    filter:= road_id = ' || road_associated  ||   -- modify the names of the attributes road_id and road_associated
                    ')')[0],
                $geometry
            )
        )
    )
```

*Screenshot: buffers created around the trees. As you see in case of the tree marked by the red arrow, it is associated to road no. 2 (red label) and not the closer road 3, so the red buffer is drawn accordingly:*

[image]

Comment: Nice approach, thank you but unfortunately the the nearest road is not always the road associated to the tree. At a crossing, a tree at 5 meter of road1 and 6 meter of road2 may be "administratively" linked to road2, that's why I had to type in the road associated with the tree!!! SO I should refer to the road identified in an atttribute of the trees.

Comment: Edited my answer to include that.

Comment: NIce! thank you very much. This sounds exactly what I was looking for. I have just to learn how to work with buffers!